# border-color adapting color attribute on OSX/IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, macos

Can somebody explain to me why in the following excample, the border color sometimes is not what is declared in the css.

URL: http://www.strasser-architektur.com.k1859.ims-firmen.de/de/werkliste/werkliste.html

On the Page you see boxes, two of those have a link around them.
Now if you look at it from a Windows PC the `border-color` displays correct on every browser i can test. But if i visit the page from my iphone, the border-color is the same as the text `color`. I can't overwrite it with css and when i change the `color` of the `<a>` with css, the `border-color` also changes accordingly.
Following is a screenshot from my iPhone 6 using Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code so we can help.

Comment: Every bit of cody is accessable in the link I posted, sorry for not telling you where the failure exactly is, but that is the whole point, I don't know the the failure is. As far as I know, Apple is too imcompetent to handle a simple border-color attribute correctly.
And this is not to hate on Apple, I like Apple alot, but this problem is blowing my mind.

Comment: Its better if you post your code here. We don't know if that link is safe and we then have to go through the hassle of viewing the source etc. Post the relevant code to the problem here or somewhere like JSFiddle.

Comment: That is the problem, i don't know what the relevant code is.
From my perspective, everything looks right in the code, so if i dont post every single bit here, there is a chance of the important part missing.

Comment: The relevant code is the CSS / HTML for the elements you are having trouble with. Where do you set the `border-color`. What is the HTML for this section that is not displaying correctly. These are the bits we need to see.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jxta970c/ I hope this will help you. I've let everything in, so you don't miss anything important. The line you are searching is row 579 of the css (when you copy it in an editor).

Comment: I provide you with the stuff you want, and then you give me nothing :(

Comment: try this : `.werkliste-inner, .texte-inner {
  border-top: 1px solid #6e6e6e;
  padding: 20px 0;
}`

Comment: Have you tried using the "!important" declaration on the border-color property? Also, a border's color will be inherited from the elements regular "color" attribute which is a useful "gotcha" to be aware of.

Comment: Thx for the comments, but i have tried both of it before, with no result. i also tried giving the `a` itself the correct border-color with no result. It is now at `!important` (if you look at it with firebug you can see it ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the dimension of the border, a rendering problem in case you use the height of 1  Pixel, this might be related to retina displays. I could easily reproduce the misbehavior in a very simple setup:

Assuming an HTML Syntax like this:

```
<div class="werkliste-inner">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Text text text</p>
</div>
<div class="werkliste-inner">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Text text text</p>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
body {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.werkliste-inner {
    border-top: 1px solid lime;
}
```

I get different colors on an iPhone 5 + iPhone 6 both with iOS 8. You'll find the fiddle to test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jxta970c/7/).

I played around with various ideas but as soon as I use a 1 pixel value, it went wrong (For example: an element with the height of 1px and a `background-color`, a `border-image`, a `background-image`). Finally I came up with a scaling solution, which worked for me:

```
.werkliste-inner-fix:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    background: #6e6e6e;
    height: 2px;
    transform: scaleY(0.5);
}
```

As you see, I use a pseudo-element and scaling to "fix" the incorrect height. This is the [test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxta970c/16/).

This concept is not new, there are [several articles](http://atirip.com/2013/09/22/yes-we-can-do-fraction-of-a-pixel/) related to retina displays and the display of pixel, but it is indeed the first time I can see an effect in color rendering.

You should be aware that this a fix for iOS devices only, so you might wrap it in a media-query like to avoid unwanted cross effects in other os.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {...}
```

Comment: That's odd, when i wanted to see the error again on my iPhone, it was gone... Well anyway, if it pops up again, I'll defenatly try your solution, it seems very reasonable (even though the problem also was shown on a normal iMac). As you put so much effort into this, I'll give you the bounty anyway :) thx for your answer